# Fluid Simulation, Render view does not look right

Tags: rendering, workflow, fluid-simulation

I am working on the Fluid Simulation. I followed an tutorial and created a water simulation.
When I switched to a render view, the colors do not change. According to online tutorials, the view should be change to b/w or mono clome. Would someone can help me how to solve this issue?
[image]

Comment: You have to bake the mesh too. These are just fluid particles.

Comment: Actually, I baked both Particles and Mesh, thank you very much for your comment. I am new to this tool and also rendering process. I really appreciate any further advice.

Comment: It's hard to recognize, please share your file here:https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Based on your first advice I revisited my file and found that the Fluid Object was just a plane. I needed to make it into a Mesh/object. That is why the file was not baked properly. Thank you very much for your advice!